# I have a trouble when i up code to host

Tags: zend-framework

This is my trouble:

> Fatal error: Class 'Default_Model_Category' not found in
>   /home/u988704384/public_html/mutilmodules1/application/modules/default/controllers/IndexController.php
>   on line 89

But in localhost, it run normal.

Please help me solve it.

In file **category.php**:(/public_html/mutilmodules1/application/modules/default/models/)

```
<?php
class Default_Model_Category extends Zend_Db_Table
{
    protected $_name = 'categories';
    public function listinfo()
    {
        $data=$this->fetchall();
        return $data;

    }
}
```

In file **IndexController.php**: (/public_html/mutilmodules1/application/modules/default/controllers/)

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
         public function indexAction()
    {
        $category = new Default_Model_Category();
        $this->view->entries = $category->listinfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just make sure to add your Zend/library directory path to your server's PHP include_path.

Answer (score 0):

The Zend Framework classes are either missing from your library folder, or not readable by the web server. First step is to see whether `/home/u988704384/public_html/mutilmodules1/application/library/Zend/Application.php` exists. If so, check the permissions on the library folder.

Comment: Thank Tim FounTain! I solved it but it have new error: 
Fatal error: Class 'Default_Model_Category' not found in /home/u988704384/public_html/mutilmodules1/application/modules/default/controllers/IndexController.php on line 89
But in localhost is normal.

Comment: Could there be some other files missing as well? If not can you edit your question to include info on where in your app the `Default_Model_Category` class is located?

Answer (score 0):

Could your current issue be as simple as a case issue?  Your class is named `Default_Model_Category` but you seem to indicate that the file name is `category.php`.  Try renaming the file to `Category.php` and see if that corrects the issue.  I know I've run into this issue before when developing on my Mac, which doesn't care about case, but my LAMP server does.